# What's the best way to standardize data in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, scikit-learn, normalization

If I have a Tensorflow model with placeholders like this:

```py
def create_LR_model(inputs):
    W = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([8, 11], mean=0.0, stddev=0.05))
    b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([11]))

    X = tf.reshape(inputs, [-1, 8])

    return (tf.matmul(X, W) + b)

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 8], name="input")
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 11])

out = create_LR_model(X)
pred = tf.nn.softmax(out, name="output")
```

And I'm going to feed in data that needs standardising/normalising (e.g. some columns have value ranges 0-100000), what's the best way to do this **inside** the model itself?

I'm basically looking (I think?) for the Tensorflow equivalent of scikit-learn's [preprocessing.scale()](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.scale.html).

Thanks in advance! Apologies if it's a silly question, I'm still quite new to this stuff...